# Android List.add function overwriting previous entries

Tags: android, listview

Im trying to populate a list with the results from a database query with the following code.

```
public List<Entry> getAllEntries() {
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_CLIENTS, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      Entry entry = cursorToEntry(cursor);
      entries.add(entry);
        Log.v("andy", "Entry:::   " + entry.toString());
        Log.v("andy","Entries::: " + entries.toString());
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return entries;
  }
```

and here is what that outputs when i run the following

```
List<Entry> e = getAllEntries();



08-16 19:53:28.274  13698-13698/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entry:::   ID: 1 / Name: andy / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 19:53:28.274  13698-13698/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries::: [ID: 1 / Name: andy / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0]
08-16 19:53:28.274  13698-13698/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entry:::   ID: 2 / Name: cg1 / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 19:53:28.274  13698-13698/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries::: [ID: 2 / Name: cg1 / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0, ID: 2 / Name: cg1 / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0]
08-16 19:53:28.274  13698-13698/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entry:::   ID: 3 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 19:53:28.274  13698-13698/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries::: [ID: 3 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0, ID: 3 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0, ID: 3 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0]
```

EDIT::
changing

```
Log.v("andy","Entries::: " + entries.toString());

to 

Log.v("andy","Entries::: " + entries.get(0));

also adding:

Log.v("andy","Entries size::: " + entries.size());

outputs:

08-16 20:33:06.054  30909-30909/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entry:::   ID: 1 / Name: andy / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 20:33:06.054  30909-30909/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries::: ID: 1 / Name: andy / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 20:33:06.054  30909-30909/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries size::: 1
08-16 20:33:06.054  30909-30909/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entry:::   ID: 2 / Name: cg1 / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 20:33:06.054  30909-30909/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries::: ID: 2 / Name: cg1 / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 20:33:06.054  30909-30909/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries size::: 2
08-16 20:33:06.054  30909-30909/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entry:::   ID: 3 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 20:33:06.054  30909-30909/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries::: ID: 3 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 20:33:06.054  30909-30909/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries size::: 3
```

EDIT*2: Further Log testing

change function to:

```
public List<Entry> getAllEntries() {
      Log.v("andy","getallentries");
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_CLIENTS, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int i = 0;
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        i++;
        Entry entry = cursorToEntry(cursor);
        Log.v("andy", "Entry:::   " + entry.toString());
        entries.add(new Entry(i, "testlistitemname"+i, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0));
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    Log.v("andy","Entries 0::: " + entries.get(0));
    Log.v("andy","Entries 1::: " + entries.get(1));
    Log.v("andy","Entries 2::: " + entries.get(2));
    Log.v("andy","Entries size::: " + entries.size());
    cursor.close();
    return entries;
  }

outputs :

08-16 20:51:03.184    6357-6357/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries 0::: ID: 3 / Name: testlistitemname3 / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 20:51:03.184    6357-6357/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries 1::: ID: 3 / Name: testlistitemname3 / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 20:51:03.184    6357-6357/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries 2::: ID: 3 / Name: testlistitemname3 / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0
08-16 20:51:03.184    6357-6357/uk.co.ab.ci V/andy﹕ Entries size::: 3
```

Why are the new entries always overwriting all of the previously added entries? I can't figure out how to make that code any simpler to figure out whats going wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code. Its what expected. You are calling `toString()` in List entries that's why the last log is to long with all result.

Comment: Now check `e.size()` after calling `List<Entry> e = getAllEntries();` is should be of size 3.

Comment: it right, it says three but then in my getView im using e.get(position); which is populating the last result three times instead of all the results once :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was due to me setting all of my Entry class variables as static, which I have learnt will make them the same over all instances of the class. So it was this that was overwriting the previous entries.

Just incase anyone else has this problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you see log properly new entries are not overwriting all of the previously added entries. It is just adding a new entry.

Your loop is running 3 times here and

```
Log.v("andy","Entries::: " + entries.toString());
```

is printing item list 1 first time, 2 second time and 3 third time.

first time

> Entries::: [ID: 1 / Name: andy / Address 1: null / Address 2: null /
>   Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null
>   / Website: null / deleted: 0]

2nd time

> Entries::: [ID: 2 / Name: cg1 / Address 1: null / Address 2: null /
>   Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null
>   / Website: null / deleted: 0, ID: 2 / Name: cg1 / Address 1: null /
>   Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob:
>   null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0]

3rd time

> Entries::: [ID: 3 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null /
>   Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null
>   / Website: null / deleted: 0, ID: 3 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null /
>   Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob:
>   null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0, ID: 3 / Name: yjh /
>   Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null /
>   Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0]

Please have look at logs properly.

Comment: surely it should come out looking more like [ID: 1 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0, ID: 2 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0, ID: 3 / Name: yjh / Address 1: null / Address 2: null / Address 3: null / Postcode: null / Tel: null / Mob: null / Email: null / Website: null / deleted: 0]

Comment: each different ID in pos 1,2,3 instead of the last added entry in pos 1, 2 and 3

Comment: This how it will give you when you do list.toString();

Comment: i feel like im missing something obvious

Comment: just try entries.get(0)  and see which item it's giving 1st one or last one. It should give 1st one.

Comment: i have update my original post with an edit showing the results

Comment: Just saw it, I am really surprised by log. Can you try entries.add(new Entry (entry)); in place of entries.add(entry);

Comment: Okay thanks and sorry I am not getting why it's happening